# spree on heroku admin button icons displaying incorrectly

Tags: heroku, admin, spree

I deployed a spree app on heroku.

Locally everything works great, in the heroku app the icon in the buttons from the admin panel display incorrectly, making it a bit difficult to use. Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJAQL.jpg

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: It would help to explain what you are expecting to see.  Is it the image that appears locally but not when deployed that is the issue?  You need to provide a bit more explanation so that we can help.

Comment: That looks like a browser issue to me, but it could be anything. Its not showing an [x] but its rending only some of the image. Have you tried it in chrome?

Comment: Try inspecting the element and getting to that image link via the browser. Pull it up in a new tab. How does it look there vs in the page?

Answer (score -2):

after rake asset:precomplie rename fontawesome icons images name

in public/assets/spree/backend/all-xxxx.css file with newly renamed images name

then git add .
commit

push to heroku

icon will be display on heroku.